# Add second audio track to MediaMuxer

Tags: android, audio, video, mediamuxer

I have a video file `.mp4` - video track only.

I'm using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaMuxer` to add audio file.
this Works good.

On the processed file i want to add another audio track.

So i'm using again `MediaExtractor` and `MediaMuxer` to kind of copy the file, (Creating video and audio tracks, reading [extractor] and writing [muxer]). In addition i'm trying to add the second audio track to the muxer. but this throws the error `Failed to add the track to the muxer`.

in this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaMuxerTest.java) we can see that muxer does not support multiple tracks.

Code From the link:

```
// Throws exception b/c 2 audio tracks were added.
muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
muxer.addTrack(MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 48000, 1));
try {
    muxer.addTrack(MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 48000, 1));
    fail("should throw IllegalStateException.");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
   // expected
}
```

Is there other way to do it ?
Elegant way ?

BTW, i'm trying to avoid using 3rd parties - like ffmpeg or so.. But if would be my only solution...

**--EDIT--**

Relevant piece of my code

```
MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
extractor.setDataSource(videoAndAudioFile);

for (int currTrackIdx = 0; currTrackIdx < extractor.getTrackCount(); currTrackIdx++) {
   MediaFormat trackFormat = extractor.getTrackFormat(currTrackIdx);
   tracksIdx.add(muxer.addTrack(trackFormat));
}

MediaExtractor extractor2 = new MediaExtractor();
extractor2.setDataSource(secondAudioFile);
MediaFormat trackFormat = extractor2.getTrackFormat(0);
tracksIdx.add(muxer.addTrack(trackFormat)); // Crashes here
```

Comment: Please paste relevant code.

Comment: Copied the relevant code from the link

Comment: I was asking about your code.

Comment: It is the same.. but i've added it now

Comment: Did you checked extractor2.getTrackCount() value? What is that ?

Comment: 1 track. This is not the problem.. I'm getting the `trackFormat` properly, and adding it properly.. According to the CTS tests link i sent, it is not allowed to add more than one audio track. Do you say it is not true? and there is a bug somewhere in my code?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361005/concatenate-multiple-mp4-audio-files-using-android%C2%B4s-mediamuxer

Comment: I saw this post and it is not my case. I am trying to add sound parallel and not one after each other. And all my audio tracks are the same format. So no problem there.

Comment: If it's helping anyone. What i've done in the end is converted the audio files to PCMs using `MediaExtractor` and `mediaCodec`. Converted them to the same sample rates, bit per sample, and channels when they are not in the same formats. Mixed the samples by myself.. And in the end encoded the PCM raw samples back to my wished format.

Comment: can you post comple code

Answer (score 1):

For someone who reaches here, I found this official doc at [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#History). Muxing Multiple Video/Audio Tracks seems not supported in old API versions and even restricted in the latest version.